# Unable to render a for loop in Twirl

Tags: scala, twirl

In a twirl template I'm trying to render a loop of strings and the current code is giving me code errors. I'm sure it's a small detail that I'm missing...

This is my template...

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        @* Here's where we render the page title `String`. *@
        <title>@title</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        @content
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is where I use this template and try to do a for loop...

```
@(names: ("George", "John", "Ally"))

@list("List of names")  {
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <ul>
    @for(name <- names) {
      <li>@name</li>
    }
  </ul>
}
```

And my controller...

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.*;

public class NewController extends Controller {
    public Result newPage() {
        return ok(views.html.newPage.render());
    }

}
```

Here is the error....

```
Compilation error
':' expected but identifier found.

In G:\Github\playExample - Copy\example\app\views\newPage.scala.html:10
6    @for(name <- names) {
7      <li>@name</li>
8    }
9  </ul>
10}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing the error message you are getting...

Comment: Seconded — do you get a compile-time error message, a runtime error, other unexpected runtime behavior, or what?

Comment: without the error is not easy to understand what's your problem... I'll leave this working example of a loop in twirl, hopefuly it can help you in the meanwhile: https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps/blob/master/app/views/index.scala.html#L121-L129

Comment: @cbley I just added the error....

Comment: @SethTisue see above

Comment: I also tried the following `@(names: Array[String] = Array("George", "John", "Ally"))` in the template and it gives me ```method render in class views.html.newPage cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String[]
  found: no arguments```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still very confusing.

I'm going to recommend you to see this project again https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps (or any simple play project).

You tag this as Scala, but your controller is clearly a java controller.

In the controller your should have something like:

```
class Controller @Inject()(val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents) extends BaseController {

  def newPage() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(views.html.newPage())
  }
```

Then in the view, you seem to have the first template ok, but I don't understand the second part you added. Is it a partial? what's the file name? where/how is it being called?

I would expect something like this:

```
@(names: List[String])

<h1>Test</h1>
<ul>
    @for(name <- names) {
        <li>@name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

I don't understand the syntax you are using